# How to retrieve data from mysql and store it in drop down list using flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter

How to retrieve data from MySQL and store it in the drop-down list and if the user selects something from the list the next dropdown shows the list that relates to the first dropdown.

Comment: Search this site for how to use API. Assuming your MySQL is on the server somewhere, you need to write API service that retrieves data from MySQL and provide them to your Flutter App. An alternative is to use Google Firebase.

Comment: Data is fetching but how to put this data in the dropdown menu?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a service method that issues an HTTP GET API call to the server.
2. Convert the JSON returned data into `List<String>`.
3. Inside your Flutter page widget build method, use `FutureBuilder` to call the above service method and get back `List<String>`.
4. In the dropdown menu widget, use the above `List<String>` to initialize the menu.
5. When the user selects one of the items, use Navigator to switch to another page passing the selected value as argument.
6. Repeat the process by calling another API to retrieve the detail record based on the passed in value and using `FutureBuilder`.
7. Display the results of the second call in the second page.